# Identify this scripting language/format

Tags: windows, user-interface, sed

This script is part of a legacy code that runs to create a GUI interface for editing text files to be used in analysis codes. There is a windows command script that references a ".sed" file which controls the formatting, editing, and help menu for the GUI. I would like to identify the coding language/rules used in these ".sed" files so that I can make a new more complicated input text file with descriptions of inputs.

Ideally, I would like to be able to use this code to create/edit ".csv" files which can be edited in Excel. This would potentially mean needing to avoid the set variable sizes/padding in the #file block of code below.

Any googling attempts to find more about the coding result in unix sed instructions that are not helpful.

UPDATE: I did find an additional exe in the shell folder of the legacy code for "sedwin.exe". When googled this seems to refer to an old "SEDT text editor for MS-DOS".

An example section from a ".sed" file is below:

```
<code>
#rem(   version description information here )

#version(){"2.0"}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------

#file(seal2,native){
  title1(A80);
  title2(A80);
  title3(A80);
  r(G10),del(A1),ll(G10),c(G10),lg(G10),dg(G10),ngroov(I10);
  ncase(I10),necc(I10),necase(I10),#for(i,1,necase,0){entlos[i](G10)};
  #for(i,1,ncase,0){
    speed[i](G10),ro[i](G10),nu[i](G10),delp[i](G10);
  }
}

#edit(seal2){
  #prompted(22,5,"SEAL2 Input Data"){
    #help(){
      "                     Code Name Here
      "",
      "Code description here"
    };
    #icon("Titles",titles){#titles();}
    #icon("Seal Parameters",seal){#seal();}
    #icon("Speed, Fluid Parameters",cases){#cases();}
  }
}

#titles(){
  #prompted(1,7,"Three Title Lines"){
    #help(){
      "These title lines will appear on the output of",
      "the program.",
      "",
      "They are useful for identifying the output but",
      "do not directly affect the results."
    };
    #datum("",title1,75,"");
    #datum("",title2,75,"");
    #datum("",title3,75,"");
  }
}

#seal(){
  #prompted(12,8,"Seal Parameters"){
    #help(){
    "Descriptions of inputs in this window.",
    };
    #datum("Shaft Radius (in)",r,15,"0.");
    #float_check("Must be > 0.0","(%g)>0.");
    #datum("Land Length (in)",ll,15,"0.");
    #float_check("Must be > 0.0","(%g)>0.");
    #datum("Seal Radial Clearance (in)",c,15,"0.");
    #float_check("Must be > 0.0","(%g)>0.");
    #datum("Groove Length (in)",lg,15,"0.");
    #float_check("Must be >= 0.0","(%g)>=0.");
    #datum("Groove Depth (in)",dg,15,"0.");
    #float_check("Must be >= 0.0","(%g)>=0.");
    #datum("Number of Grooves (0=plain seal)",ngroov,15,"0");
    #int_check("Must be >= 0","(%d)>=0");
    #datum("Number of Eccentricities",necc,15,"1");
    #int_check("Must be between 1 and 10","(%d)>0&&(%d)<11");
    #icon("Entrance Loss Cases",losses){#losses();}
    }
}

#new_file(seal2){
file_type=seal2;
unit_type=native;
titles=New;
title1=;
title2=;
title3="(SEAL2 Data File)";
del=",";
seal=New;
ll=0.0;
r=0.0;
c=0.0;
lg=0.0;
dg=0.0;
ngroov=0;
losses=New;
necc=1;
necase=1;
entlos[1...necase]=0.1;
cases=New;
ncase=1;
speed[1...ncase]=0.0;
delp[1...ncase]=0.0;
nu[1...ncase]=0.0;
ro[1...ncase]=0.0;
}
</code>
```

Comment: If you have access to a Linux machine (or WSL), what happens when you run the `file` command on that file? It can often identify a file. It may not work, but you could try

Comment: I don't have access to one right now but I can try that next week. Thank you for the suggestion.